# XPath 2.0 Query: 1 element, check between two dates

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0, xpathquery

This is how my XML-file looks like

(1 record: )

```
<movie>
    <idMovie>4373</idMovie>
    <Name>Casanova</Name>
    <Timestamp>2012-11-15 15:00:00</Timestamp>
    <is3D>1</is3D>
    <isNL>0</isNL>
    <Room>35</Room>
    <Theater>Kinepolis Brussel</Theater>
</movie>
```

As I need to check which movies are played in the next week, I tried an XPath (2.0) expression like:

```
/movie[Theater="xxxx"][Timestamp>'2012-11-09']/Name
```

Which returns me all the movies that have a timestamp greater than 29th October. But I need all the movies between 29th October and 5th of November. I think i'll need a BETWEEN-function or something like that.

Hopefully someone is able to help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `and`:

```
[Timestamp>'2012-10-29' and Timestamp<'2012-11-05']
```